# validateDOMNesting(...): Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>

Tags: reactjs

For some reason my code throws the following error:

Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of . Make sure you don't have any extra whitespace between tags on each line of your source code

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>. Make sure you don't have any extra whitespace between tags on each line of your source code.
    at tbody
    at table
    at div
    at DisplayFlights (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:228:66)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38680:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39102:5)
    at div
    at App
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39040:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37398:5)
```

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {Link, useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

function DisplayFlights() {
  const {from,to,departureDate} = useParams()
  const [flightData,setFlightData] = useState([])
  const [isLoading,setLoading]=useState(true)



  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('http://localhost:8081/flightnews/flights?from='+from+'&to='+to
    +'&departureDate='+departureDate).then(res=>{
      setFlightData(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
    })
  },[from,to,departureDate])
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Flights:</h2>
      <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Airlines</th>
            <th>Departure City</th>
            <th>Arrival City</th>
            <th>Departure Date and Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody>{!isLoading?flightData.map(flight=><RowCreator item={flight}/>):""}
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

function RowCreator(props){
  var flight = props.item;

  return <tr><td>{flight.companyName}</td>
    <td>{flight.departureCity}</td>
    <td>{flight.arrivalCity}</td>
    <td>{flight.estimatedDepartureTime}</td>
    <td><Link to={'/passengerDetails/'+flight.id}>Select</Link></td></tr>
}
export default DisplayFlights;
```

I console.log([from,to,departureDate]) to see if my data is fetched and I he is . So I tried multiple solutions in this line of code "

```
<tbody>{!isLoading?flightData.map(flight=><RowCreator item={flight}/>):""}</tbody>
```

to solve my problem but it didn't find yet.
Thanks in advance for helping me

Comment: 1. add a key when you map items. 2. Try `<tbody>{!isLoading?flightData.map((flight, index)=><RowCreator key={index} item={flight}/>):null}`